# create-react-app doesn't work as expected

Tags: reactjs, asdf-vm

I have the following setup in my system

```
%asdf shim-versions create-react-app
nodejs 12.16.3

% asdf current nodejs
nodejs          14.17.6         /Users/user/.tool-versions
```

But when I run npm to create react-app as follows get the following output

```
% npm init react-app react-complete-guide
No preset version installed for command create-react-app
Please install a version by running one of the following:

asdf install nodejs 14.17.6

or add one of the following versions in your config file at /Users/user/.tool-versions
nodejs 12.16.3
```

I have tried `asdf reshim nodejs`

Is there something wrong in my setup?

Answer (score 0):

It's npx create-react-app not npm create-react-app.

Comment: the page mentions both. https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: Have you tried npx create-react-app? Npx and npm aren't the same thing npx executes something npm is a package manager.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by uninstalling the old version of node which was what the create-react-app was tied to.

Found out how by doing `asdf shim-versions create-react-app` and uninstalling that node version.

Comment: What is `asdf` can you change it to correct keyword (in your post for question too)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).